# Xml configuration in spring

Tags: spring, spring-ws

How is it that when I add a namespace in spring bean configuration file I am able to reduce xml configuration considerably?

For example:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services

http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd">


    <sws:annotation-driven />


</beans>
```

this fragment allows me to not define PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified

```
<sws:annotation-driven/>
```

From the documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html-

> By using the 
>   element in our configuration, we
>   enable the detection of the
>   @PayloadRoot annotations. It is
>   possible (and quite common) to have
>   multiple, related handling methods in
>   an endpoint, each of them handling
>   different XML messages.

It basically means that you can specify the annotation in your Java file to define the endpoint -

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas", localPart = "HolidayRequest")
```

Hence you no longer need to specify the configuration in an XML.

Answer (score 2):

These are "configuration macros" that came into fashion with Spring 2.5. They reduce the donkey-work required when declaring common arrangements of beans, replacing them with the macro.  Examples from Spring include `<context:annotation-driven/>`.

In your example, `<sws:annotation-driven/>` replaces a bunch of Spring WS endpoint mapping and handler beans, which you would otherwise have to declare explicitly.

Note that simply declaring the XML namespace does not in itself do anything, it's the `<sws:annotation-driven/>` that does the work.

Answer (score 0):

When the

```
<sws:annotation-driven />
```

is detected in the config, the framework auto-registers a slew of framework beans to detect end points mappings, to act as the message receiver etc. The message factory, message receiver etc are all auto-registered. This is basically a short-cut for the more straight-forward cases wherein we just want the defaults for all these beans.